# Windows+CloudFormation :User doesn't have permission to call IAM:CreateUser

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, web-deployment, bootstrapping, aws-cloudformation

I cannot find decent documentation about using CloudFormation with Windows 2008 R2 AMI. AWS recently released a new Windows AMI which has CloudFormation tools pre-installed.

The AMI itself can be found here : 
https://aws.amazon.com/amis/microsoft-windows-server-2008-r2-base-cloudformation

**Aim**: I want to use CloudFormation so that during bootup the instance can download the latest dlls and config files of my application from S3.

- In that AMI, by default, where are these tools located under C:\ ? ( I did a search in the file system and couldn't find it)
- Do these tools already run by default automatically on bootup ? Or do I have to write a script to do so and re-bundle (remake) an EBS backed AMI ? I would like to test this !
- To try out the sample templates provided by AWS for Windows, I tried launching the Windows Sharepoint template given here : https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/Windows_Single_Server_SharePoint_Foundation.template .When I try to launch this stack given by that template, it gives me the following error and rollsback :
  **AccessDenied. User doesn't have permission to call iam:CreateUser**

As per the "Account Owner", my IAM account belongs to the Administrators Group which "cannot create new users", if that's the case how should I tackle this issue.

As per my understanding, if I have to use CloudFormation to retrieve metadata, the CloudFormation stack creates a new IAM user with only "DescribeStackResource" action permission and this new IAM user lives as long as that stack lives.

Answer (score 0):

It will be available under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap` but not sure whether it will run on boot, that I have to verify.